# Expose pulseaudio channel to JACK

Tags: pulseaudio, jack

I have PulseAudio running on top of JACK, but PulseAudio simply exposes a single input/output to JACK. Since PulseAudio supports several channels, is there anyway I can expose different channels to JACK independently. I want this to support recording from Skype some guitar lessons and to better control all the values when playing guitar with backing tracks.

Comment: Have you tried loading `module-jack-sink` multiple times? Or with more than 2 channels? (I don't run Pulseaudio on top of Jack, so I cannot try).

Comment: No, and I am not sure how to do that

Comment: How did you configure everything to have PulseAudio running on top of JACK?

Comment: I use cadence, which provides a GUI button to enable the PA sink/source

Comment: You are looking for a mixer or DAW that provides mixing controls - JACK is only a patch panel.

Answer (score 0):

to add a Pulseaudio JACK Sink (to send Pulseaudio playback to JACK)

```
pactl load-module module-jack-sink channels=2 connect=0
```

to add a Pulseaudio JACK Source (send JACK audio to Pulseaudio capture)

```
pactl load-module module-jack-source channels=2 connect=0
```

[module options](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#module-jack-sink)

'connect=0' prevents automatic connection to JACK 'system:playback' output

'channels=2' restricts connection to stereo pair

commands can be repeated to add multiple connections
if 'Pulseaudio JACK Sink' is already loaded then command to add another sink connection will create 'Pulseaudio JACK Sink 01'

Comment: This doesn't solve my issue at all. I already have a way of connecting Pulseaudio to JACK. What I want is a way to expose each Pulseaudio channel to JACK independently

Comment: Cadence can only create one set of Pulseaudio sink/source connections. commands can be used when JACK is running to add additional connections. comment Apr 11 asked about multiple sinks too. if this is not what you are seeking probably need clarify the original question